# Safest way to redirect in smarty tpl

Tags: php, smarty

I have this code below that I want to redirect them to home if they are logged in, but I just don't know how to go about it.. what is the best way to redirect a user, the fastest and best way overall inside a tpl file?

```
{if isset($smarty.session.user.id)} redirect here? {/if}
```

How can I do this? and what is the best way...

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not doing it in a smarty template, but on the php script. If for some reason you can't do it, use javascript inside the {if}, i.e.

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```